ValueError: Exception encountered when calling PositionalEmbedding.call()
I am running Neural machine translation with a Transformer and Keras. https://www.tensorflow.org/text/tutorials/transformer
pt is an tokenized vectors of size (64, 79). For the following class, PositionalEmbedding.call() throws an error.
class PositionalEmbedding(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
  def __init__(self, vocab_size, d_model):
    super().__init__()
    self.d_model = d_model
    self.embedding = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size, d_model, mask_zero=True) 
    self.pos_encoding = positional_encoding(length=2048, depth=d_model)

  def compute_mask(self, *args, **kwargs):
    return self.embedding.compute_mask(*args, **kwargs)

  def call(self, x):
    length = tf.shape(x)[1]
    x = self.embedding(x)
    # This factor sets the relative scale of the embedding and positonal_encoding.
    x *= tf.math.sqrt(tf.cast(self.d_model, tf.float32))
    x = x + self.pos_encoding[tf.newaxis, :length, :]
    return x

This call is throwing an error.
    embed_pt = PositionalEmbedding(vocab_size=tokenizers.pt.get_vocab_size(), d_model=512)
    pt_emb = embed_pt(pt)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-167-44987cede320> in <cell line: 4>()
      2 embed_en = PositionalEmbedding(vocab_size=tokenizers.en.get_vocab_size(), d_model=512)
      3 
----> 4 pt_emb = embed_pt(pt)
      5 en_emb = embed_en(en)

1 frames
<ipython-input-166-e9ab4e283481> in call(self, x)
     11   def call(self, x):
     12     length = tf.shape(x)[1]
---> 13     x = self.embedding(x)
     14     # This factor sets the relative scale of the embedding and positonal_encoding.
     15     x *= tf.math.sqrt(tf.cast(self.d_model, tf.float32))

ValueError: Exception encountered when calling PositionalEmbedding.call().

Invalid dtype: <property object at 0x7a6808eb53f0>

Arguments received by PositionalEmbedding.call():
  • x=tf.Tensor(shape=(64, 70), dtype=int64)

I tried to change the datatype to int32 and it didn't work.

It looks like you're encountering a type issue with the d_model parameter in your PositionalEmbedding TensorFlow layer. The error suggests d_model might be incorrectly treated as a property rather than an integer. Check and ensure that d_model is being initialized correctly as an integer and is not a property or function. You can debug this by adding a print statement like print("d_model type:", type(self.d_model)) in the call method before it's used to verify its type. This will help confirm that d_model is an integer and not causing the issue.
import tensorflow as tf
   
class PositionalEmbedding(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, vocab_size, d_model):
        super(PositionalEmbedding, self).__init__()
        self.d_model = d_model  # Ensure this is always an integer
        self.embedding = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size, d_model, mask_zero=True)
        self.pos_encoding = positional_encoding(length=2048, depth=d_model)

    def compute_mask(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.embedding.compute_mask(*args, **kwargs)

    def call(self, x):
        if not isinstance(self.d_model, int):
            raise ValueError(f"Expected d_model to be an integer, got {type(self.d_model)} instead")
        
        length = tf.shape(x)[1]
        x = self.embedding(x)
        
        # Scale the embeddings by the square root of d_model
        x *= tf.math.sqrt(tf.cast(self.d_model, tf.float32))
        
        # Add positional encoding
        x += self.pos_encoding[:, :length, :]
        return x

def positional_encoding(length, depth):
"""Helper function to generate positional encoding"""
    # You should replace it with your actual function to generate positional encodings.
    return tf.random.normal([1, length, depth])

# Example usage:
try:
    layer = PositionalEmbedding(vocab_size=1000, d_model=512)
    dummy_input = tf.random.uniform((1, 64), dtype=tf.int32, maxval=1000)  # Example input
    output = layer(dummy_input)
    print(output)
except ValueError as e:
    print(e)


Thank you for your response, Alef! When I try the call method, it shows self.d_model is indeed an integer.

Just change the vocab_size=tokenizers.pt.get_vocab_size() to vocab_size=tokenizers.pt.get_vocab_size().numpy()
Like:
embed_pt = PositionalEmbedding(vocab_size=tokenizers.pt.get_vocab_size().numpy(), d_model=512)
embed_en = PositionalEmbedding(vocab_size=tokenizers.en.get_vocab_size().numpy(), d_model=512)


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
